# Create a program to establish an ssl connection with mysql client and to decrypt the client messages

Tags: mysql, ssl, encryption, openssl

I need to write a program which can establish a ssl connection with mysql client and also it will decrypt all the client encrypted messages . The authentication will mutual which means both client and server will use ca ,certificate and key file.
Is there any open source tool available ? if not then I will dig mysql source code .Your suggestions will be highly appreciated .

Comment: You may need to be less general in your question. What part of the program do you need help with?

Comment: @Lt_Shade I did modify the question .I actually need suggestion which will help me to understand how is mysql using ssl .I wrote client and server program which can establish ssl connection with each other but my server program is not working fine with mysql client .

Comment: You seem to be asking how to mount a man-in-the-middle attack on SSL and MySQL. I'm not saying it's impossible, but you're not exhibiting much grasp of the essentials here, and you haven't provided anything in the way of motivation either.

Comment: @EJP I don't have to do man in the middle attack .The product(P) which require this feature resides between client and server so client will have ca,cert and key file which was generated and signed by P .I didn't find any tool which can do it and so I will have to dig mysql source code .I know its difficult that's why I am interested to know about behaviour .

Comment: You still haven't defined your requirement sufficiently to get an answer.